# Java - charAt with multiple answers

Tags: java

I'm having some trouble with my code, I am trying to test if a position in a char is equal to an integer. The way I have it setup is like so:

```
    for(int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
        if(str.charAt(i) == '[1234567890]') {
            System.out.println(str);
        }
    }
```

However I'm getting the error "unclosed character literal" when I try to compile. Does anyone know why I'm getting an error, or can explain a more simple way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
if ( Character.isDigit(str.charAt(i)) )
```

You have to check that every character is a digit to check if your string contains and integer.

Answer (score 3):

`'[1234567890]'` is not a `char`. A `char` is a single character. This is why your code doesn't compile.

Comment: I'm trying to compare the position to any integer.

Comment: @user1327636: The position is `i`, where is the integer?

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be trying to use regex notation inside a character literal. That won't work. If you want to use a regex, you can write:

```
        if(str.substring(i, i+1).matches("[1234567890]") {
```

but it's better/simpler/faster/clearer to write:

```
        if(Character.isDigit(str.charAt(i))) {
```

On the other hand, even once you make this change, your code will print `str` several times if it contains several digits. Is that really want you want? I wonder if you want something more like this:

```
    if(str.matches("\d+"))
         System.out.println(str);
```

which will print `str` once if *all* of its characters are digits.

Answer (score 0):

Your code cannot be compiled because in java character `'` ( single quote ) is used to mark one character. In order to define string you should use double quote `"`.

In your case I believe that you wanted to check whether your string contains digits only and were confused with regular expression syntax you tried to use incorrectly.

You can either rewirte your if statement as following:

char c = str.charAt(i);
`if(c>= '0' && c <= 9) {`

or use pattern matching, e.g.
`Pattern.compile("\\d+").matcher(str).matches()`

In this case you even do not need to implement any loop.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to write something simple like this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
    //check str.charAt(i) is one of the chars in 1234567890
    if("1234567890".indexOf(str.charAt(i))>=0) {   
        System.out.println(str.charAt(i));
    }
 }
```